# PhpStorm override function

Tags: php, phpstorm

Return type of [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) function has changed in PHP 8.0.

With PhpStorm 2022.1.3 + Php Inspections (EA Extended) 4.0.7.1 inspect code (PHP 7.2 level), I get many:

> [EA] '$xyz' may not support offset operations (or its type not annotated properly: `[bool, array]`).

In PhpStorm configuration, is there a way to override default explode function?

I tried to add *.phpstorm.meta.php/explode.php*, but this is not working. I think it's wrong.

```php
<?php
namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    override( explode,
        function explode(string $separator, string $string, int $limit): array {
            return [];
        }
    );
}
```

I ask that because, I get the previous "error" with the following code with PHP 7.2-7.4, and not with PHP 8.0 (for `$gps[0]` and `$gps[1]`):

```php
$gps = explode(',', $result['GPS']);
if (count($gps) == 2) {
    $items['lat'] = $gps[0];
    $items['lng'] = $gps[1];
}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) `override()` syntax and usage syntax is wrong: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-1) metadata.html#override . How it's used in PhpStorm's own mefadata: https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/blob/master/meta/.phpstorm.meta.php#L63

Comment: 2) TBH, instead of trying to use some metadata function without knowing how it all works ... why don't you describe the actual issue that you have? Please provide 1) a small code snippet that shows the issue and 2) screenshot of the error (how it looks in the IDE). Because I do not see such an error in my PhpStorm 2021.1.3 in a basic `explode()` usage.

Comment: 3) PhpStorm's stub for `explode()` declares `string[]` return type for PHP 8.0+ and `string[]|false` for earlier versions. https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/blob/master/standard/standard_1.php#L994 4) It could also be an issue with your EA plugin version (need to see the code sample for that).

Comment: Thanks, sorry, yes, I added a code sample.

Comment: My previous solution to avoid the "error", is to use: `$gps = (array) explode(...`

Comment: 1) Technically the error description is correct as `explode()` can return `bool`, But then, the lines with `$gps[0]` and `$gps[1]` will not be executed in this example (as it will not pass the `if (count($gps) == 2)` condition. 2) The issue is: I do not see such an error for your code example (unless I have disabled it, which does not seem to be the case after checking the settings). Have you tried that small code snippet separately, not inside your real file? https://i.imgur.com/x85hDzY.png . Just in case: PhpStorm 2022.1.2, Php Inspections ​(EA Extended) plugin v4.0.7.1

Comment: No, but now yes... And I didn't get your result: https://www.zupimages.net/up/22/25/qcy8.png

Comment: Sadly I still cannot reproduce the issue in my test project. What inspection is that? Place caret on that `$gps[0]`, use `Alt+Enter` (or click on a light bulb icon) to bring the quick fix/intentions menu. If you use `arrow right` on a menu entries, it will bring a submenu that allows to locate that inspection in the settings. What inspection that would be?

Comment: BTW: will it still show an error if you use `if (is_array($gps) && count($gps) == 2)` ?

Comment: This is "Array and string offset validity". And yes `is_array($gps)` or `!empty($gps)` fix the "error".

Comment: I see, Thanks. It is disabled by default (by the plugin author). What I may say: 1) the same as I have stated in *"Technically the error description is correct..."*. If `$gps` would be `bool` then the appropriate code where it is used will simply not run. This suggests that it's an EA plugin issue. You better report there -- https://github.com/kalessil/phpinspectionsea/issues?q=Array+and+string+offset+validity 2) In the meantime use the workaround guard code to ensure that the type is `array`.